# Bad Data loaded from yahoo for app chart and also for yahoo chart

Tags: yahoo-finance

I have an app I bought that used yahoo stock data.  It works fine for most tickers except ^ndx.  It has a jump in the data at 01/09/12- 01/10/12 that is false from there backwards, ie, the prices displayed are all way too high compared to the correct data.

Same thing when I use the same symbol directly in yahoo chart!  But the historical data downloaded from yahoo is correct!

I have talked to the developer of the app, and he says he does NOT have this problem.  He uses the IOS data from Yahoo for his app.

What can account for these conflicting results.

Oh, and if I bring up a fresh copy of the app, or after it has been sitting there for a time, the data for the same ticker looks good!!  But the yahoo chart is always bad.

Comment: Two other things on the last sentence; The data looks good only once, then the same bad display when I press the chart display button again. Also, if its related, I can't display ^dji on the app, but can on Yahoo chart. There must be something in my Ipad configuration [and the PC?] that is causing this, since the developer does not have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/b?s=%5endx

%5E is a caret encoded.

Comment: I get this. What is caret encoded? I did this a minute ago.  http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bc?t=1y&l=on&z=l&q=l&p=&a=&c=&s=%5ENDX%2C+&ql=1